# Android Notification PendingIntent problem

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a alarm manager which is calling an activity class named ScheduleAlert.

```
public class ScheduleAlert extends ActivityGroup {

   private String notificationAlart, editEventid;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ...........
                ..........
                // ************* Notification ************//
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Myapp", nextAlarmTime);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Myapp";
        CharSequence contentText = notificationAlart;

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MyApp.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ScheduleAlert.this, 0, notifyIntent,android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,pendingIntent);

            notifyDetails.flags = Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            mNotificationManager.notify((int) editEventid, notifyDetails);

        // ************* Notification ************//
        this.finish();
      }

      public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

      }

}
```

I want that the indent of MyApp activity should fire when I tap on the notification massage. At the time of notification I want just sound and vibration. But now the I am getting the sound and vibration, and also the MyApp activity is fired, which I do not want actually. What is problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots and lots of strange things with this code:

- I have no idea why you are extending `ActivityGroup` for this code
- Do not use `getApplicationContext()` in most circumstances, such as this one
- Since this is an `ActivityGroup` (for whatever reason) and not a `Service`, it is misleading to the OS and the user to have `FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE`
- `FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE` and `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` make little sense in combination

However, I would not expect any of this to cause `MyApp` to automatically start. In fact, AFAIK, there is no circumstance in which a `Notification` will automatically invoke its `PendingIntent` without the user tapping on it. I suspect that your real problem lies elsewhere.